# Cannot use scrollTo offset when using window.location.hash

Tags: jquery, scrollto, smooth-scrolling

I have a single page site with a `position: fixed;` header containing main nav. I'm using [**this plugin**](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) to smooth scroll to each section via the main nav. Because of the fixed header I need to set an `offset` which = height of the header. Everything works fine using this initialisation:

```
$('.nav-main a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchorLocation = $(this).attr('href');
    $.scrollTo(anchorLocation, 700, {
        offset: -86
    });
});
```

But I need the URL to include the section ID e.g. http://domainname.com/#about which each link has in it's `href` e.g. `<a href="#about">About</a>` so I use this:

```
$('.nav-main a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchorLocation = $(this).attr('href');
    $.scrollTo(anchorLocation, 700, {
        offset: -86,
        onAfter: function() {
             window.location.hash = anchorLocation;
        }
    });
});
```

So that fixes up the URL but screws up the header in that sometimes it disappears once the smooth scroll has finished but then will come back into view if you scroll again and the `offset` just doesn't work. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Someone posted the below solution but then removed it but it works in terms of not having to use the plugin but the `offset` only works in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) in IE 8/9 & Firefox once the scrolling animation has stopped it will honour the `offset` for about a millisecond then snap to the top of the viewport.

```
var headerHeight = $('[role="banner"]').outerHeight() -1;

$('.nav-main a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollToID($(this).attr('href'));
});

function scrollToID(ID){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(ID).offset().top - headerHeight
    }, 700, function() {
        window.location.hash = ID;
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `window.location.hash = anchorLocation;` after the `var anchorLocation` line?

Comment: That didn't work, see my **EDIT** above.